# Testing Async Methods with Jasmine - Wrong Test Case Failing

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular2-services

I'm unit testing a function in angluar2 which returns a Promise. Below is a simplified version of my function:

```
getItems(orderId: string): Promise<ItemsModel> {
    return this.authHttp.get('https://my-api-url').toPromise<ItemsResponseModel>().then(ItemsResponseModel => {
        let itemsModel = new ItemsModel();

        // Mapping values from ItemsResponseModel to ItemsModel

        return itemsModel;
    });
}
```

authHttp is the service from angular2-jwt which returns an Observable after each method call.

This is how I mock my service:

```
let callback: string;

beforeEach(() => {
    itemsResponseModel = new ItemsResponseModel();
    mockAuthHttp = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockAuthHttp', ['get']);
    mockAuthHttp.get.and.callFake((url: string) => {
        callbackUrl = url;
        return Observable.of(itemsResponseModel);
    });
    myService = new MyService(mockAuthHttp);
});
```

Now, I want to test this function. So, this is the way with which I'm testing it:

```
it('should call with correct url', (done: any) => {
    myService.getItems('123').then(itemsModel => {
        expect(callbackUrl).toBe('https://my-api-url');
        done();
    });
});

it('should have correct value1', (done: any) => {
    myService.getItems('123').then(itemsModel => {
        expect(itemsModel.value1).toBe('something');
        done();
    });
});
```

These simple test cases were also failing until I added that "done" function and then they passed.

The problem is when I want to use my new it_multiple function for a test, I can't pass a "done" function. I wrote that function to support multiple test cases in just one test. I don't know how I can extend this function to accept a "done" function. I hope after passing "done" function in a correct way, I wouldn't have problems with tests written by this function.

```
function it_multiple(description: string, callback: any, testCases: Array<Array<any>>): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < testCases.length; i++) {
        let testCase = testCases[i];
        it (`${description} (${testCase.join(', ')})`, () => {
            callback.apply(null, testCase);
        });
    }
}

it_multiple('should have correct value1 for different item ids', (itemId: string, expectedValue1: string) => {
    myService.getItems(itemId).then(itemsModel => {
        expect(itemsModel.value1).toBe(expectedValue1);
    });
}, [
    [null, 'nothing'],
    [undefined, 'nothing'],
    ['123', 'something']
]);

it('some other tests', () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Currently, not also do these test cases fail, but also Jasmine shows the next "it" description as the failed test. It says "some other tests" has failed plus two of those three cases in it_multiple! Any ideas how I can have a "done" function for my it_multiple? I had the same issue with "it" before that "done". I think that's the problem here too. If you think otherwise, please also let me know...